# Kingdoms of Amalur Reckoning damage or physical damage

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

There are some types of damage "enchantments" in game its: damage (+15% damage), physical damage (+15% physical damage) and elements damages.
My question is what is difference between damage and physical damage ? I have +10% damage components in my sword an some +damage components in my armor. Is that same like physical damage, because i have pure mighty character.

And some little additional question. Is +% Armor "enchant" counted by armor value of concrete piece where enchant is or its by overall armor rating ?

Sorry for my bad english and thanks for answers :)

Answer (score 2):

**10% damage** affects all damage you deal, from the hit of your sword to its poison enchantment to the Shock spell (if you still have it).

**10% Physical damage** only applies to the base damage of your weapons, any enchantments that say Physical on them and Physical spells such as Quake. This does not include Bleeding damage, which has its own bonus damage category.

**10% Bleeding** damage only affects bleeding damage you deal, fire only affects fire, etc... you have to deal some in order for a % bonus to help you at all.

**10% elemental damage** is the only one I'm not sure about. I would *suspect* that Elemental damage simply means "everything that's not physical". It *might* only mean "fire, ice, and lightning", but leave out unusual damage types such as Poison.

Comment: Does +10% damage include Critical Hit Damage as well though?

Comment: That's a question I would have a hard time testing without an expensive respec, sorry. I have seeen a fateweaver several times, but have neither tried out Finesse nor gemmed for criticals - they happen VERY infrequently for me.